# Синтаксис data-

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, теги, атрибуты

А что за синтаксис data- (чему равны значения этих свойств)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это рекомендуемый префикс для пользовательских атрибутов

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset

Answer (score 0):

[`data-`](http://htmlbook.ru/samouchitel-html5/atributy-data) - атрибут для хранения какой-либо информации. Например, не уникальный идентификатор.

```js
<div data-number="23">Див с data-атрибутом, хранящим число<\div>
```